# How to get javascript to output min-height not only height

Tags: jquery

The following code outputs `style="height....`

But i want it to output `style="min-height.....`

```
$( window ).load(function() {

    boxes = $('.equals');

    minHeight = Math.max.apply(
        Math, boxes.map(function() {

            return $(this).height();
        }).get());
    boxes.height(minHeight);

});
```

Comment: Do you want the `minHeight` variable to be the `min-height` of the boxes object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the css function of jQuery.

So in your case it would be:

```
boxes.css("min-height", minHeight);
```

Comment: Since the OP mentions `output` I believe they are looking to retrieve the min-height. Your code currently `sets` it. Might be best to show both options :)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$(this).css('min-height')
```